# Simplifying mesh (selecting a face by its number or coordinates)

Tags: mesh, point, simplify, meshlab, face

I have a microCT scan of a porous material. I simplify the mesh in Meshlab and when I want to import it in a Finite Element software (COMSOL), I get the error message saying "**The face 14775 can not be parameterized**" and it also gives me the location of a point as follow:

**Point 21717
Coordinates: 253, 176, 62**

How can I fix this error in the meshlab? Is it possible to select a face or a point by its number or coordinates?

Thanks,
Hamed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Conditional Face Selection** filter (search for its name) and set as condition `(fi==14775)` and the 14775th face will be selected and shown in red.